# Error getPlayer(args[0]);

Tags: java, minecraft, bukkit

I made this code, and if you type: /gmspec in MC i should set your gamemode to Spectator mode. But the only thing it says is:'An Internal error occurred while attempting to perform this command.'. In the console it says: arrayindexoutofboundsException: 0... Pls help, i dont know whats the problem...

```
    if (commandLabel.equalsIgnoreCase("gmspec")) {


        Player p = (Player) sender;
        Player target = Bukkit.getServer().getPlayer(args[0]);


        if (args.length == 0) {
            p.setGameMode(GameMode.SPECTATOR);
            p.sendMessage(ChatColor.GREEN + "Your own gamemode has been changed!");
            return true;
        }

        if (target == null) {
            p.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "The player " + target.getName() + " is not online!");
            return true;

        }
        target.setGameMode(GameMode.SPECTATOR);
        target.sendMessage(ChatColor.GREEN + "Your gamemode is set to Spectator mode. You are not a banaan that just tries every command without any permission...");

        if (sender.hasPermission("gamemode.spectator")) {

            p.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "You banaan. Y u still try? U no permission has u dumb shit");
        }
        if (sender instanceof ConsoleCommandSender) {


        }


    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Look at where you check whether `args.length` is 0. Now look at where you're using `args[0]` (which isn't valid if `args.length` is 0).

Comment: I dont know what you mean? should i first say    if(args.length=0)    and then    args[0]    ???

Comment: Yes - but you should understand *why* first. Do you understand that you can't access an element of an array if that element doesn't exist? `args[0]` accesses the first element of the array. So if the array is empty, it fails.

Comment: so it should be like this??? `Player p = (Player) sender;
            

            if (args.length == 0) {
                p.setGameMode(GameMode.SPECTATOR);
                p.sendMessage(ChatColor.GREEN + "Your own gamemode has been changed!");
                return true;
            }
            Player target = Bukkit.getServer().getPlayer(args[0]);
`

Comment: first, player p = ...
if statement
target ...
rest of code?

Comment: Rather than me spoon feed you every change, I suggest you think it through yourself. What do you want to do if `args` is empty? What do you want to do if `args` is not empty? Make sure you don't try to access an element in `args` that doesn't exist.

Comment: Thank you dude, thanks for helping me! I love you!... Now i need to fix that u cant execute it from the console... But you dont have to spoon feed me that! Thanks for helping me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you're checking the length of the arguments *after* you attempt to fetch them. You have to make sure that there are one or more arguments before you attempt to get the argument, or you'll get an [`ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.html)

Also, you're going to want to check that the command sender is a actually `Player` before casting them to a `Player`. If you don't do this, you will not be able to run the command from anything but a `Player`.

To fix this, you could replace every `p.sendMessage()` with `sender.sendMessage()`, and only cast `sender` to a `Player` if `sender instanceof Player`

So, your code could look something like this

```
if(commandLabel.equalsIgnoreCase("gmspec")){
    if(args.length == 0 && sender instanceof Player){//check if the sender is a Player
        Player p = (Player) sender; 

        p.setGameMode(GameMode.SPECTATOR);
        p.sendMessage(ChatColor.GREEN + "Your own gamemode has been changed!");

        return true;
    }
    else{
        Player target = Bukkit.getServer().getPlayer(args[0]);

        //the rest of the code
    }
}
```